# How do you run a Chrome application in a tab instead of a separate window?

Tags: google-chrome

How do you run a Chrome application in a tab instead of a separate window?

I suppose that would be possible if you know the URI of that application, but how do you discover the URI?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298166/run-chrome-packaged-apps-inside-of-browser-tab ?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576615/open-chrome-extension-in-a-new-tab) of any use? By default there's no way to do it without default functionality written into the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the URI in the extensions page of chrome, or if the app is not listed there you can see them at `chrome://apps/` when you "view in web store" the link contains the URI. Alternatively, you can make a shortcut of the app and then check the "target" field under the properties.

The window behavior is recorded in the manifest.json in the app directory. For example I have an app called gistbox that has an entry:

```
  "launch": {
     "container": "panel",
     "height": 768,
     "web_url": "https://app.gistboxapp.com/",
     "width": 1200
  },
```

changing the "panel" value to "tab" should change the behavior. Alternatively right-clicking on the app icon under `chrome://apps/` also gives me an option to uncheck "open as window".

Another 'app' (extension technically) that opens as a window but doesn't have "container" field nor any right-click option is "Web Server for Chrome". It has a background entry instead:

```
"background": {
     "scripts": [ "underscore.js", "encoding.js", "common.js", "log-full.js", "mime.js", "buffer.js", "request.js", "stream.js", "chromesocketxhr.js", "connection.js", "webapp.js", "websocket.js", "handlers.js", "httplib.js", "upnp.js", "background.js" ]
  }
"optional_permissions": [ "background" ]
```

And within the background.js there the window is created by: `chrome.app.window.create`. I haven't tested but I think changing that to `chrome.app.tab.create` should cause the app to start in a tab instead of window.